# Wondering if Possible

Tags: excel

I have had a request for me to change the format of some documents I work on (quite a number of them so would be great if this is possible)...Please see details below:

I have a spredsheet of information that looks like below:

[image]

I was wondering if it is possible through any excel function/functions or other methods to change the format of this to something similar to the following:

[image]

Any help/advice anyone could provide would be great.

O I have also tried using pastespecial (transpose).. this does not work as there is sometimes more than one CN per person

Many Thanks

Paula

Comment: Why are the % in multipe columns in the new layout , is this a mistake?

Comment: Apologies yes... they should have been all in one column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a Sheet1 like this:

[image]

Then you could create a second sheet like this:

[image]

with formulas in

A2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$A,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/3)+2)`

B2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$1:$1,,MOD(ROW(1:1)-1,3)+3)`

C2: `=INDEX(Sheet1!$A:$E,MATCH($A2,Sheet1!$A:$A,0),MATCH($B2,Sheet1!$1:$1,0))`

The 3 within the INT and MOD are because you have 3 different CNs. You have to change this if you have more or less CNs.

The +2 and +3 are offsets because your percent-data begins in row 2 and column 3. You have to change this if your data starts elsewhere.

Fill down the formulas until values for names are 0 and values for percent are #N/A.

Now you can filter only the percents which are greater than 0.

Comment: This works absolutly perfectly... however I was wondering If you use a first and second name like Jane Smith spread over columns A & B what changes would you need to make to the code for this to work? Think this may be a safer option as some people on my list have the same name and same spelling.

Comment: The names have to be unique, that's true. The simplest way to achieve this would be to have first and second name concatenated in column A. Or to concatenate them with `=A2&" "&B2` in another column. But then you have to customize the formulas relate to this column instead of A. A better approach is to have a unique ID per person instead of the names.

Comment: thats brillaint thanks for all your help :) shall go look into that now

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to do this is to select and copy the horizontal cells into a text editor that will let you do find/replace with escape characters (I use notepad++). You want to change the search mode in the find/replace window to extended and replace all of the tabs with newline characters (replace \t with \n). Then copy and paste it back into excel.

Comment: Thanks I shall give this a try shortly